# Provide text column length on composite unique index creation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord, composite-index

I'm trying to create an index on a new table that requires uniqueness on the `agency_id` (integer) and the `IP` address (text). I know that I need to provide a length on the index for `IP`. But I'm having issues assigning the length to *just* the `IP` column.

```
def up
   create_table :whitelisted_ips do |t|
     t.integer :agency_id
     t.text :ip
     t.timestamps
   end

   add_index :whitelisted_ips, [:agency_id, :ip], unique: true, length: 15
end
```

This code returns the error

> Mysql2::Error: Incorrect prefix key; the used key part isn't a string, the used length is longer than the key part, or the storage engine doesn't support unique prefix keys: CREATE UNIQUE INDEX `index_whitelisted_ips_on_agency_id_and_ip`  ON `whitelisted_ips` (`agency_id`(15), `ip`(15))

because it is attempting to put the length on the integer field. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should provide a hash for the `length` parameter instead:

```
add_index :whitelisted_ips, [:agency_id, :ip], unique: true, length: { ip: 15 }
```